# Получение капчи при работе с VK API в Java приложении

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю программу, которая работает через VK API.

Периодически VK выдает капчу. Я собираюсь автоматически распознавать её при помощи специального сервиса, куда необходимо отправлять изображение капчи закодированное base64.

VK API выдает качу ссылкой такого вида
https://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid=656102463982&s=1

На этой страничке уже есть капчf в base64(его можно увидеть в браузере Google Chrome - нажать F12 и там Sources).

Как получить его в виде строки для дальнейшей передачи?

Пробовал отправлять GET запрос по адресу https://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid=656102463982&s=1

В ответ приходит какая то каша(на скрине, даже не копируется нормально). 
[image: Ответ]

Что это за ответ и как с ним дальше работать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем разобрался сам. Прост получаю картинку вот таким способом

```
    static String URL = "https://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid=656102463982&s=1";
static Image loadImage() {
    try {
        String fileName = "1.jpeg";         
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL(URL));
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", file);
        return img;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Ну а дальше уже её можно кодировать и отправлять на распознавание. Даже на диск не надо записывать, это для теста сделано.